# Parse raw body on cloudflare-worker service(Non NODE)

Tags: javascript, http-post, cloudflare-workers

I've created an api server'ish environment on cloudflare using cloudflare-worker and there is no node server running(cloudflare-worker is pretty much serverless event handler service). It does provide the configurations to handle any subdomain calls much like how api works. I've used a package called `cf-worker-router` to do so. 
My cloud service looks like this:

```
import { ApiError, ApiRedirect, DomainRouter, FetchRouter } from 'cf-worker-router';

const router = new FetchRouter();

// add the cloudflare event listener
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  router.onFetch(event);
});

router.route('/users', 'POST', async (event) => {
  // automatically converts anything not of Response type to ApiResponse
  return await event.request.text();
});
```

And what I did was create a POST request to the url and supplied some body to the request. I was able to get the request text successfully but now I can't figure out how to parse the text I received.

When using the request as `multipart/form-data` request and the received body text is as follows:

> "----------------------------093590450792211419875705\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\nJon Doe\r\n----------------------------093590450792211419875705--\r\n"

I tried sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I the response text as such:

> "name=Jon%20Doe"

And Similar for `application/json` request:

> "{\n\t\"name\": \"Jon Doe\"\n}"

Since cloudflare is not using nodejs server, `body-parser` can't be applied here. This service is pretty much an open api so it needs to take care of all sorts of request  content types. Is there any way to identify and decode the strignified contents from any of these content types to a valid object in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle form data uploads, you can use the [request.formData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData) method which will return a promise of a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.

For example:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})


async function handleRequest(request) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const name = formData.get('name');
  return new Response(`Hello ${name}`);
}
```